# Unable to generate FlatList of Expo Contacts using async

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to setup expo contacts to generate the list of contacts on the device. However i am failing to understand and implement it.

The following code doesn't make any change in useEffect and output remain "empty" only.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import * as Contacts from 'expo-contacts';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { useState } from 'react/cjs/react.development';

export default function Contacts(){

let [contacts, setContacts] = useState(null)

let contact = ''
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.Emails],
        });

        if (data.length > 0) {
          contact = data[0];
          setContacts(data)
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  let output = 'empty'
  useEffect(() => {
    if(contacts){
        output = 'updated'
    }else{
        output = 'still empty'
    }
  }, [contacts])

  return (
    <View>
        <Text>{output}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy.

**Here is the working example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/basic-contacts-app-using-expo-contact)**

Scan the QR code from your Expo Go app to see it working.

[image]

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as Contacts from 'expo-contacts';

export default function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const fetchContacts = async () => {
    const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === 'granted') {
      const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
        fields: [Contacts.Fields.Emails, Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
      });
      console.log(data[0])
      setContacts(data);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title={'Fetch Contacts'} onPress={fetchContacts} />
      <Text>{('Total Fetched Contacts: ', contacts.length)}</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={contacts}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return <Text>{item?.name}</Text>;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginTop: 24,
  },
});
```

Comment: I am using almost the same code but In my case the list shows on android and on simulator and emulator but after app uploaded, on iphone the screen goes white hen i open the screen. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: I have not checked the code on IOS so I can't help you in this case.